# how to give an upper bound on the minimum singular value of the derivative of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

Now I have a matrix $\begin{equation}\label{key}
R = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
2a_1 & 2a_2 & \cdots & 2a_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(T-2)a_1^{T-3} & (T-2)a_2^{T-3} & \cdots & (T-2)a_n^{T-3} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$, where $T = 2n+1$, and $\forall i, -1< a_i < 1$.

My question is how to give an upper bound on  the minimum singular value of $R$.

Comment: Two elementary remarks 1) Your matrix is $(2n) \times n$, right ? 2)  The first line of zeros isn't very "sympathetic" nor usual, and I think it would be better to get rid of it.

Comment: (1) The matrix $R$ is $2n \times n$.
(2) You are right! The zeros in the first line are removed without affecting the result.